# Значение частицы "ли"

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

Подскажите пожалуйста, Что обозначает "уж не тайное ли общество самоубийц?" Я вижу очень часто, что есть такая конструкция: "прилагательное + ли". Что это обозначает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particle *ли* which is used to form general questions (aka Yes/No questions) and which can be translated into English as 'whether' does not form any constructions with adjectives. This particle is never used as the first word in a sentence. Since Russian has free word order, you normally begin a question with a theme, the word which names what you are inquiring about, then goes the description of the kind of information you would like to get about the theme. Actually, you can well do without the *ли*, marking the theme by mere intonation, but if you do use *ли*, you put it after the theme, and very often the theme is the adjective, you often need to know whether (*ли*) the object possesses the quality described by the adjective.

In your example *уж не тайное ли общество самоубийц?* the *ли* is put after *тайное*, 'secret', which means the intention of the person who asks this question is to find out whether the society is *secret* or not.

The rule of thumb is, if you see or hear a question with *ли*, you have to confirm or negate the relevance of the fact expressed by the word after which the *ли* is placed.

Comment: So I can essentially place ли wherever I want to in this sentence?

Comment: @MattSteinberg - Definitely no! First, you've got to build a sentence in such a way that it begins with the theme, then you can place _ли_ after the theme: _Много ли он выпил?_ 'Was it much that he drank?', _Красным ли он это покрасил?_ 'Did he paint that red [or any other color]?', etc.

Comment: Ok thank you! It seems like some type of passive voice construction almost

Comment: @MattSteinberg Positioning of "ли" corresponds to Wackernagel's law: it is placed after the first fully stressed word of the sentence (after "бы" if it is also after the first fully stressed word).

Answer (score 1):

Generally ли has many meanings, but in the sentence you brought, I'd rather look at the construct **"уж не ... ли ..."**. This specific construct is usually there to either emphasize suspicion in which the speaker is somewhat sure, or to convey sarcasm or skepticism. The first meaning could be translated to English quite straight forward. Translating sarcasm or skepticism is more tricky. Let's try your sentence:

*"уж не тайное ли общество самоубийц?"* could mean that person came to conclusion that s/he is indeed dealing with "secret suicide society" (the emphasis is not on secret here, but on the fact that he discovered what s/he is dealing with), but they cannot be 100% sure, so they convey their suspicion. E.g. *"could it be a secret suicide society?"* *"I wonder if it's a secret suicide society"*

But if your text means this more in a sarcastic or skeptical way, where person is trying to say that secret suicide society is sort of irrelevant nonsense, then a more appropriate translation would be sceptic *"are you trying to (blame it) on secret suicide society?"* or sarcastic *"and it was a secret suicide society of course"*.

Answer (score 0):

*"ли" is an auxiliary particle for help making questions from statements.*

in this context "уж не тайное ли (pointed object) общество самоубийц?", "ли" may mean "whether" or "if" by sense - "(pointed object) should be a secret suicide society, is'nt it?". by putting this particle just near the questionable subject (or if to be precise, enclosing questionable subject in the pair "уж не ... ли"), the speaker try to introduce an additional question tone to this subject making this statement an ironical or mockery one.